# Как из питона 3 выполнять произвольные bash команды?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bash, debian

Как из питона 3 выполнять произвольные bash команды? например: `bash("ifconfig")`.
Может есть библиотека?

Comment: os.system("ifconfig")

Comment: то самое. спасибо

Comment: @Fat-Zer, как раз **команды интерпретатора bash** (всякие там `bg`, `fg`, `set` и т.д. и т.п.), насколько я понимаю, таким образом выполнить нельзя. я понимаю, что автор вопроса не понимает, в чём разница между программами и командами интерпретатора, но всё же…

Comment: @alexanderbarakin под магическим словом bash обычный пользователь понимает все, что вводится в терминал. Встроенные команды bash можно глянуть набрав /bin/bash help.

Comment: @Hellseher, да, я в курсе про бардак в терминологии (вероятно, в разной степени он присутствует в любой области знаний). но само его (бардака) наличие, мне кажется, не может служить поводом для его (бардака) усугубления.

Comment: извиняюсь. не правильно сформулировал вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выполнить исполняемый файл, вовсе не нужно bash запускать. Операционная система позволяет новые дочерние процессы создавать без запуска оболочки.

В Питоне для этого [можно `subprocess` модуль использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess 

subprocess.run(['ip', 'addr'])
```

Если необходимо выполнить команду, использующую bash функциональность. К примеру, чтобы найти строчки общие для двух файлов c помощью [замены процессов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279):

```
subprocess.run('comm -12 <(sort -u a) <(sort -u b)',
               shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

если не указать `executable`, то используется `/bin/sh` оболочка, которая может не поддерживать bash-измы.

Чтобы перенаправить вывод команды, можно передать stdout, stderr параметры или вызвать обёртку `subprocess.check_output()`. Наличие `check` в имени или `check=True` аргумент проверяют возвращаемый код команды (если не ноль, то выбрасывается исключение).

Чтобы взаимодействовать c командой (ввод/вывод) пока она ещё выполняется до её завершения, [можно явно `subprocess.Popen` объект создать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).